# Field is always null in Spring Boot Postmapping method

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to bind my HTML table with all fields to Java code in Spring Boot.
Therefore, I have annotated my method with Postmapping, too.

I was already able to show all the fields in Thymeleaf and I was also able to set the checkBox value ( true / false ) accordingly.

This is my Thymeleaf HTML code:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/mitarbeiterverwaltung}" th:object="${users}" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <table border="1" align="center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- <th:text = "#{mitarbeiterverwaltung.active}>Active ( Tick ) / Passive</th>-->
                <th>Active ( Tick ) / Passive</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Anzeigename</th>
                <th>Dienstnummer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="user, itemStat : *{users}">
                <td><input  th:field="*{users[__${itemStat.index}__].isActive}"
                            th:checked="${user.isActive}"
                            class="checkBox"    
                            type="checkBox"
                            name="checkBox" 

                /></td>
                <td><input  th:field="*{users[__${itemStat.index}__].id}" 
                            readonly/></td>
                <td><input  th:field="*{users[__${itemStat.index}__].username}" 
                            readonly/></td>
                <td><input  class="anzeigename" 
                            type="text" 
                            name="anzeigename" 
                            th:field="*{users[__${itemStat.index}__].anzeigename}" 
                            th:id="${itemStat.index}" 
                            readonly/></td>
                <td><input  class="dienstnummer" 
                            type="text" 
                            name="dienstnummer" 
                            th:field="*{users[__${itemStat.index}__].dienstnummer}" 
                            th:id="${itemStat.index}" 
                            readonly/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" th:value="Speichern"/>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And this is my Java code, where the field isActive of UserCreationDto is always null.

```
@PostMapping
public String updateActivePassiveUser(@ModelAttribute UserCreationDto userTableSettings,
        @RequestParam("checkBox") String checkBoxName, BindingResult result, Model model, Errors errors) {

    logger.info("Method {} called in {}", new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName(), this.getClass().getName());

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        logger.error("Error in {}", new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
        return "error";
    }

    List<Benutzer> users = userManagementServiceImpl.getAllUsers();

    userManagementServiceImpl.updateActivePassiveUser(1, 0);

    return "redirect:/mitarbeiterverwaltung?success";
}
```

Here is a picture of the field in Java code where the method is annotated with @PostMapping

[image]

And so does my @RequestMapping look like:

[image]

This is my @RequestMapping method:

```
@RequestMapping
public String showUserManagement(Model model) {
    logger.info("Method {} called in {}", new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName(), this.getClass().getName());
    List<Benutzer> users = userManagementServiceImpl.getAllUsers();
    userForm = userManagementServiceImpl.saveUserForm(users);
    model.addAttribute("users", userForm);
    return "mitarbeiterverwaltung";
}
```

My UserCreationDto where all the fields get added to a list:

```
public class UserCreationDto {

private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

public void addUser(User user) {
    this.users.add(user);
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

And my simple POJO class with all the fields

```
@Data

   public class User {
    //@SafeHtml prevents XSS ( Cross-Site Scripting )
    @SafeHtml
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String anzeigename;
    private String dienstnummer;
    private long id;
    private Boolean isActive;
}
```

The other fields like anzeigename, dienstnummer, id, and username are filled within my Java code, however, isactive is always null.

Maybe, someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what about trying your REST API with Postman to make shure the Spring Boot Application works fine?

Comment: I already did that but when sending my request, I always get my login page at first. I am not so used to Spring Boot and Postman and I am still learning.

Comment: so add basicauth to your spring security config and try it with postman first ... if the REST API works than you could work the frontend out .. otherwise it would be difficult... another thing could be the developer tools of your browser ... you get them by hitting F12 for chrome and firefox i guess .. after reloading the page you could see your request which is send by the browser ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to many options set. You don't need th:checked:

```
<input  th:field="*{users[__${itemStat.index}__].isActive}"
        class="checkBox"    
        type="checkBox"
        name="checkBox" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I do not have a problem with the HTML code. I think my problem is with my Java code. When submitting the form, my field isActive within @ModelAttribute UserCreationDto userTableSettings is always null.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way now, but it is not really nice.

```
@PostMapping
public String updateActivePassiveUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") UserCreationDto userTableSettings,
        @RequestParam List<String> searchValues, BindingResult result, Model model, Errors errors) {
```

The field searchValues contains all the checkBoxes that are ticked.
This is my view:

```
<td><input  type="checkbox"
    name="searchValues"
    th:value="${user.id}"
    th:checked="${user.isActive}"
/>
```

Now, the only problem that I am having is how to update my column that is of type Boolean in Postgresql?

For accomplishing this task I call this:

```
userRepo.updateActivePassiveUser(new Boolean("False"), id);

@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE benutzer SET active = :active WHERE id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional
void updateActivePassiveUser(@Param("active") Boolean active, @Param("id") long id);
```

However, the value in my database never changes.

Maybe, someone could give me a last hint, please!